# How to integrate forward/back button in WebView in tabbed application?

Tags: ios, button, webview, tabbed

Is there a way to integrate an forward/back button in a WebView in a tabbed application? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why a tabbed application matters but in general you can create a UIControl object like `UIButton`, add a target and selector to it and in the function you call `goBack` or `goForward` on the `UIWebView` .